# How to subscribe a user to a websocket channel in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm a backend dev coming from a Python/Django background, and there, there's a module that introduces channels to websockets.

For example, user 1 and 2 can subscribe to a channel i.e. `/payment/1` and user 3 and 4 can subscribe to a channel `/payment/2`. If a message gets sent to a channel, then only those users would get the message.

I'm finding the Spring websocket somewhat difficult to understand, so this might be something trivial.

Comment: so, is there a question ?